# Iterating over a loop with two vectors of different lengths

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, literate-programming

I have two dataframes:

```
harv<-structure(list(spp = c("Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)", 
"Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)", "Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)", 
"Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)", "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)", 
"Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)", "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)"
), number = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

oth<-structure(list(spp = c("Tink", "Chii", "Blue", "Red", "Blue")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I want to iterate over the loop so that every time the spp name contains "Other" it will replace it in order of the `oth` data frame. Here is what the `harv` data frame looks like:

```
                                                       spp number
1    Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)      1
2 Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)      2
3                         Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      2
4    Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)      4
5 Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)      5
6                         Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      7
7    Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)      9
```

When I run through this loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(oth$spp)) {
  # Find indices where "Other" is present in spp
  indices <- grep("Other", harv$spp)
  # Replace spp values at the found indices with oth$spp[i]
  harv$spp[indices] <- oth$spp[i]
}
```

It gives me a data frame that only pulls the name `"Tink"` in the oth$spp[i] vector. The data frame looks like this:

```
 spp number
1                             Tink      1
2                             Tink      2
3 Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      2
4                             Tink      4
5                             Tink      5
6 Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      7
7                             Tink      9
```

How do I create a loop so that each "Other" `harv$spp` is replaced sequentially with what is in the `oth` vector?

I want to get a dataframe that looks like this, replacing each "Other" with what is in the `oth` data frame in the same order as that data frame:

```
spp number
1                             Tink      1
2                             Chii      2
3 Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      2
4                             Blue      4
5                             Red       5
6 Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      7
7                             Blue      9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the number of times 'other' appear in spp is equal to the number of rows of `oth` df, then do:

```
harv[grep('Other', harv$spp), 'spp'] <- oth
```

---

But this might not hold true hence we have to take the minimum of the two:

```
idx <- grep('Other', harv$spp)
n <- min(length(idx), nrow(oth))

harv[head(idx,n), 'spp'] <- head(oth, n)
harv

                              spp number
1                             Tink      1
2                             Chii      2
3 Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      2
4                             Blue      4
5                              Red      5
6 Red Drum (a.k.a. Redfish or Red)      7
7                             Blue      9
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop -- the functions needed to do this in base R are *vectorized*, meaning that the function will operate on all elements of a vector without needing to loop through and act on each element one at a time:

```r
idx <- which(startsWith(harv$spp, "Other"))
harv$spp[idx] <- oth$spp[seq_along(idx)]
```

Also be careful of using `grep` here which takes a regular expression to match a string pattern (maybe this is what you want to do). The way you have written it this will match "Other" anywhere in your string.

---

It is easiest to understand the issue you have encountered if you step through your loop one element at a time:

```r
i <- 1
indices <- grep("Other", harv$spp)
# [1] 1 2 4 5 7

oth$spp[i]
# [1] "Tink"

harv$spp[indices]
# [1] "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)"   
# [2] "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)"
# [3] "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)"   
# [4] "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Amberjack)"
# [5] "Other species (please list species name; i.e. Tarpon)"
```

After the first iteration it is important to note that you have overwritten all values of `harv$spp[indices]` with "Tink" before the next iteration:

```r
i <- 2
indices <- grep("Other", harv$spp)
# integer(0)

oth$spp[i]
# [1] "Chii"

harv$spp[indices]
# character(0)
```

Since you have overwritten all values of `harv$spp` at indices `1 2 4 5 7`, `grep` returns an empty numeric vector because no strings contain "Other". Since you have no indices then using the selection with an empty vector also returns an empty character vector (e.g. `harv$spp[integer(0)]` will always return `character(0)` since `harv$spp` is character). So, none of your remaining iterations do anything.

Comment: I used `startsWith` here since it seems most appropriate for your data. However, if you need to match "Other" anywhere then you could use `grep("Other", harv$spp, fixed = TRUE)` instead of the entire `which(...)` expression.